# Recursively or iteratively retrieve key-value combinations from a HashMap

Tags: java, recursion, hashmap, combinations, cartesian-product

I want to retrieve `k`,`v`-pairs from a `HashMap`.
The entrys are like this:

```
a = 3,4
b = 5,6
```

and so on. I need combinations of these values.

```
a=3, b=5
a=3, b=6
a=4, b=5
a=4, b=6
```

I don't know how many keys and how many entrys the values have. With `entrySet` I can get the values but not combinations. It looks like recursion but how?

Here's my code:

```java
HashMap<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
String str;

while ((str = file.readLine()) != null) {
    
    // ... logic
    
    map.put(key, value);
}

System.out.println("number of keys: " + map.size());
for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + value);
    }
}
file.close();
```

Comment: I'm not clear: is "a" your key and "3" (from a's list) your value, or is "3" your key from a and "5" your value from b?

Comment: a is the key, 3 and 4 are strings. therefore "String[]". the value is String[]

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following code:

```
public void mapPermute(Map<String, String[]> map, String currentPermutation) {
    String key = map.keySet().iterator().next(); // get the topmost key

    // base case
    if (map.size() == 1) {          
        for (String value : map.get(key)) {
            System.out.println(currentPermutation + key + "=" + value);
        }
    } else {
        // recursive case
        Map<String, String[]> subMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>(map);

        for (String value : subMap.remove(key)) {
            mapPermute(subMap, currentPermutation + key + "=" + value + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

No guarantees on memory efficiency or speed.  If you want to preserve the order of the keys in the map, you will have to pass in a `TreeMap` and change the code to use a `TreeMap` under the recursive case.

As the base case suggests, I'm assuming you have at least one entry in your map.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you really want a [`MultiMap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).  In particular, [`ArrayListMultimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) allows duplicate entries:

```java
ArrayListMultimap<String, String> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();

for each line in file:
    parse key k
    for each value in line:
        parse value v
        map.put(k, v);

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entries()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
}
```

---

If you want a cartesian product of maps, you could compute that directly using recursion, or you could iterate over the maps: create a list of iterators and iterate odometer-style; when iterator N reaches its end, advance iterator N+1 and reset iterators 1..N.

---

Just poked around and found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719594/iterative-cartesian-product-in-java).

So I'd recommend you use guava's [`Sets.cartesianProduct`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release04/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#cartesianProduct%28java.util.Set...%29) for the cartesian product. Here's my poking around code, which you could adapt to your input logic:

```java
String key1 = "a";
Set<Integer> values1 = Sets.newLinkedHashSet(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
String key2 = "b";
Set<Integer> values2 = Sets.newLinkedHashSet(Arrays.asList(5, 6, 7));
String key3 = "c";
Set<Integer> values3 = Sets.newLinkedHashSet(Arrays.asList(8, 9));

List<String> keys = Arrays.asList(key1, key2, key3);
Set<List<Integer>> product = Sets.cartesianProduct(values1, values2, values3);
for (List<Integer> values : product) {
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); ++i) {
        String key = keys.get(i);
        int value = values.get(i);
        System.out.print(key + "=" + value + "; ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: A `HashMultimap` would prevent duplicate entries.  But I'm still really unclear on your goal.

Comment: ok. i get a text-input. this gets into the map. key is a. the values are stored in a String[]. i need the values later as separate strings. so that is why it is String[] and not just string. i need every combination from the key-value-pairs as in my first post.

Comment: In that case you just need to check if the key-value pair already exists in the map.

Comment: I think I just got that you want the product of the maps--as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714108/cartesian-product-of-arbitrary-sets-in-java

Comment: well, it is more like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710670/c-permutation-of-an-array-of-arraylists the method given in your link... how can this be applied to my case? sorry, i am not a really good programmer...

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a *Cartesian product* of map key-value combinations using a *map and reduce* approach.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVRNa9tAEL37Vww6rYqyIe7HIXUFoRQKbU8uvYQe1vLYXne1K3ZHDsL4t7uzG8skURyH0gUhMfPem8/VWm3UxXr@Z7/XdeM8wZoNsiVt5JuPo4EtkEdVR9eoMioE@ImBYDsCPk07M7qCQIr4tXF6DrXSVkzJa7u8/Q3KL0N@AMfzQzWTe2cBPahkTgOfok@6hThi@5OprACLd0fCNnvLluxdtiuG4NkA/D6CP2S7nCvoYd91oMkwmbKEytUzToZTkmjJd1MkkR@aIPJBvMvLSGXf5Klkr1gOOJLFBcJFCTfeqy706iiXSL@UaVHkw0iP2JvIPjQs0b5hJ/ICNi8RK2cMViQ@37@dD5JcTJvDPVtZaOuaJ@ssuAU0SvsQPwwzQFtyoCBwiQaTaVimx3lboRDRe1Uk0DiPiSfD6Z4@yCBOQ9uUQ4qtrUUfhxNOl7kwirg1glFXfbTx@WiPotpKEXJcfFIoa54VSAPiZxyDb8/Cn78WfCl4C@Mif1VhFf2l4AV@jVgtm5ZujEkN@AfO@JUcj9R6C/V59C5/cchpoXi4D4f9H7fY0Qr9nQ5YgLKAdUPdiYV1/osJ2CvHNGSCH9Qf/D@ibEvcswKcn6eV7GCjfHdExGLkghVVtRLTLhDWkinX1w2Pl4w9NHk32u33fwE)

```java
Map<String, String[]> map = Map.of(
        "a", new String[]{"3", "4"},
        "b", new String[]{"5", "6"});
```

```java
List<Map<String, String>> comb = map.entrySet().stream()
        // Stream<List<Map<String,String>>>
        .map(e -> Arrays.stream(e.getValue())
                .map(v -> Map.of(e.getKey(), v))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        // summation of pairs of list into a single list
        .reduce((list1, list2) -> list1.stream()
                // combinations of inner maps
                .flatMap(map1 -> list2.stream()
                        // concatenate into a single map
                        .map(map2 -> {
                            Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
                            m.putAll(map1);
                            m.putAll(map2);
                            return m;
                        }))
                // list of combinations
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        // otherwise, an empty list
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

```java
// output, order may vary
comb.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output, order may vary:

```
{a=3, b=5}
{a=3, b=6}
{a=4, b=5}
{a=4, b=6}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Cartesian product of map values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68506104/16649492)</sup>