# Function Result is Generic

Tags: function, delphi, generics

I need something like this:

```
  function fn_get_all_propperties (obj : TObject) : TObjectList<TTypeKind>;
```

But:
**[DCC Error] uFuncMain.pas(20): E2511 Type parameter 'T' must be a class type**

What type should be the result of a function?

Comment: See [`What does the E2511 Type parameter 'T' must be a class type compiler error mean?`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17741092/576719).

Comment: I dont understand anything(

Comment: @user1879841: The official [Overview of Generics](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Overview_of_Generics) and especially [Constraints in Generics](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Constraints_in_Generics) should help you get started. What is your Problem? `TTypeKind` is not a class, it's an enumeration variable. You want a `TList<>`, not a `TObjectList<>`: `function fn_get_all_propperties (obj : TObject) : TList<TTypeKind>;`

Comment: Big thx for explanation! Its usefull!

Comment: I suggest using TArray<TTypeKind> because otherwise the calling side of your function is responsible to destroy the returned list. Or you use the Spring4d interface based collections types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `TObjectList` is defined as follows:

```
TObjectList<T: class> = class(TList)
  ....
end;
```

The `T: class` in the definition means that the generic parameter `T` is [constrained](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Constraints_in_Generics) to be a `class`. But `TTypeKind` is not a class. It is a value type.

So the compiler rejects your attempted generic instantiation as being invalid because it does not satisfy the constraint.

So you cannot use `TObjectList<T>` here and instead should use `TList<T>`. Your function should be defined like this:

```
function fn_get_all_properties(obj: TObject): TList<TTypeKind>;
```