# Hadoop cartesian product of list with itself

Tags: java, join, hadoop, cartesian-product

**Using Hadoop MapReduce**

I have a list as input:

1. A
2. B
3. C

And I want to get the Cartesian product of the list with itself:

- A => A,f(A,A)
- A => B,f(A,B)
- A => C,f(A,C)
- B => A,f(B,A)
- B => B,f(B,B)
- B => C,f(B,C)
- C => A,f(C,A)
- C => B,f(C,B)
- C => C,f(C,C)

f() is a function that gives a value for a pair of keys.

How do I do that a in a simple manner using Hadoop MapReduce in Java?

Of course I can't hold the entire input list in memory.

Thanks!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719594/iterative-cartesian-product-in-java

Comment: Hi Chris,
It is indeed trivial to do a Cartesian multiplication in Java when you can iterate both arrays in the same code.
However, I need a solution for Hadoop, where data is streamed and partitioned.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you use Pig Latin? As well as I know, Pig uses a tricky way to do the  Cartesian product (called cross join in Pig). It's a complex manner so that I do not suggest you to implement it by yourself.

Comment: I need to do it directly without using Pig.
Why would implementing a join of a list on itself should be highly complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it in Java map reduce. Let us assume, you want to do cross product between two files A and B with splits 3 and 4 respectively. Then you have to write custom input format that splits up the two datasets and then ensured there was a SPLIT for each subset of data.

So your splits would look like:

```
 A1 X B1
 A1 X B2
 A1 X B3
 A1 X B4
 A2 X B1
 A2 X B2
 A2 X B3
 A2 X B4
 A3 X B1
 A3 X B2
 A3 X B3
 A3 X B4
```

Use link https://github.com/adamjshook/mapreducepatterns/blob/master/MRDP/src/main/java/mrdp/ch5/CartesianProduct.java for your reference.

Comment: Can you please explain *how* to implement that custom dataset to split up the two datasets correctly using Java+MapReduce?