# Generation permutations of multiple lists of different types

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

I want to generate permutations of multiple lists of different types. Let me put an example as explaining it in english would be tough.

```
Class Rule {
private List<Long>  ids;
private List<String> names;
private List<ABCEnum> enums;
}
```

I want to generate permutations in form of output objects which looks like this:

```
Class Output {
Long id;
String name;
ABCEnum enum
}
```

Test Example-

Input--

```
Rule:
ids -- 1,2
names -- abc,bcd
enums -- NEW,OLD
```

Generated Output objects: ( total --  2 * 2 * 2 = 8 objects)

```
1,abc,NEW
1,bcd,NEW
1,abc,OLD
1,bcd,OLD
2,abc,NEW
2,bcd,NEW
2,abc,OLD
2,bcd,OLD
```

Things I have tried:
tried to map permutations of a string example to my problem with no luck.
I can go into for loops but that is not a good solution.

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Any help in solving this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how many entries the rule has or does that vary?

Comment: Right now I have five fields in the rule(shown 3 in example above) but this can increase in future.  As far as the each list goes, it could be unlimited number of entries in a list.

Comment: Enter "Cartesian product" in the search box; you'll get dozens of results like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719594/iterative-cartesian-product-in-java

Comment: Permutation is the wrong term. They're about orderings of input data.  As @m69 says, you're looking for a cross product.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Long id : ids)
    for (ABCEnum e : enums)
        for (String name : names)
            System.out.println(id + "," + name + "," + e);
```