# Cartesian Product of an unbound number of arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Suppose you have an unbound list of named arrays:

```
ArrayNode[] vertexes = new ArrayNode[] {
    new ArrayNode("nouns", new String[]{"John", "Mary"}),
    new ArrayNode("verbs", new String[]{"Eats", "Works", "Plays"}),
    new ArrayNode("objects", new String[]{"Food", "Computer", "Guitar"})
 };
```

Given an order to follow, say "***nouns->verbs->objects***", what algorithm can we use to associate all elements of the arrays in the given order? The output is something like the following:

```
["John Eats Food"], ["John Eats Computer"], ["John Eats Guitar"], 
["John Works Food"], ["John Works Computer"], ["John Works Guitar"], 
..., ..., ..., 
...,                 ["Mary Plays Computer"], ["Mary Plays Guitar"]
```

The number of arrays is unbound and the sequence can be any for the given number of arrays.

## Solution

Using Java 8 and Google Guava 19 **Lists.cartesianProduct**
Take a look at the answer to this at [Iterative Cartesian Product in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719594/iterative-cartesian-product-in-java/37490796#37490796)

Comment: I'm trying to go with a mix of DFS and BFS... Not sure if that's the right approach...

Comment: I'm looking for a Java implementation... But yea, do you have reference to a simple backtracking example?

Comment: The link provided in the comment by Oriol has a few good implementations that you could port to Java. See especially [this functional one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36234242/539048) and [this recursive one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29585704/539048).

Comment: I implemented using Google Guava's List.cartesianProduct method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could traverse the arrays in `inorder` fashion to get the output in the desired order.