# Algorithm for dynamic combinations

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinatorics, combinations

My code has a list called INPUTS, that contains a dynamic number of lists, let's call them A, B, C, .. N. These lists contain a dynamic number of Events

I would like to call a function with each combination of Events. To illustrate with an example:

```
INPUTS: A(0,1,2), B(0,1), C(0,1,2,3)
```

I need to call my function this many times for each combination (the input count is dynamic, in this example it is three parameter, but it can be more or less)

```
function(A[0],B[0],C[0]) 
function(A[0],B[1],C[0]) 
function(A[0],B[0],C[1])
function(A[0],B[1],C[1])
function(A[0],B[0],C[2]) 
function(A[0],B[1],C[2])
function(A[0],B[0],C[3])
function(A[0],B[1],C[3])

function(A[1],B[0],C[0]) 
function(A[1],B[1],C[0]) 
function(A[1],B[0],C[1])
function(A[1],B[1],C[1])
function(A[1],B[0],C[2]) 
function(A[1],B[1],C[2])
function(A[1],B[0],C[3])
function(A[1],B[1],C[3])

function(A[2],B[0],C[0]) 
function(A[2],B[1],C[0]) 
function(A[2],B[0],C[1])
function(A[2],B[1],C[1])
function(A[2],B[0],C[2]) 
function(A[2],B[1],C[2])
function(A[2],B[0],C[3])
function(A[2],B[1],C[3])
```

This is what I have thought of so far:
My approach so far is to build a list of combinations. The element combination is itself a list of "index" to the input arrays A, B and C. For our example:

my list iCOMBINATIONS contains the following iCOMBO lists

```
(0,0,0) 
(0,1,0) 
(0,0,1)
(0,1,1)
(0,0,2) 
(0,1,2)
(0,0,3)
(0,1,3)

(1,0,0) 
(1,1,0)  
(1,0,1) 
(1,1,1)
(1,0,2) 
(1,1,2)
(1,0,3) 
(1,1,3)

(2,0,0)
(2,1,0)  
(2,0,1) 
(2,1,1)
(2,0,2) 
(2,1,2)
(2,0,3) 
(2,1,3)
```

Then I would do this:

```
foreach( iCOMBO in iCOMBINATIONS)
{
      foreach ( P in INPUTS )
      {
           COMBO.Clear()
           foreach ( i in iCOMBO )
           {
                 COMBO.Add( P[ iCOMBO[i] ] )
           }
           function( COMBO ) --- (instead of passing the events separately)
      }
}
```

But I need to find a way to build the list iCOMBINATIONS for any given number of INPUTS and their events. Any ideas?

Is there actually a better algorithm than this? 
any pseudo code to help me with will be great.

C# (or VB)

Thank You

Comment: You might also want to read up on capitalization conventions ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx

Comment: Capitalization conventions aside, you are talking about a "Cartesian product", such as taking X coordinates and Y coordinates, and looking at all possible points (X,Y). Starting from the correct name of the problem should give you some headway. See my comments below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array to hold the indexes for each list. Example:

```
List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>> {
  new List<int> { 0,1,2 },
  new List<int> { 0,1 },
  new List<int> { 0,1,2,3 }
};

int[] cnt = new int[lists.Count];
int index;
do {
  Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", cnt.Select((c,i) => lists[i][c].ToString()).ToArray()));
  index = cnt.Length - 1;
  do {
    cnt[index] = (cnt[index] + 1) % lists[index].Count;
  } while(cnt[index--] == 0 && index != -1);
} while (index != -1 || cnt[0] != 0);
```

Comment: logged-in just to upvote this solution. Something I have been looking for. Another modification to that would be - instead of listing 0, 1, 2, 3 in a list - just set the number of items in the list i.e. 4. This will of course not give us the choice to exclude some of the items, but then again, it's very situational. p.s. I would have given more upvotes for the sheer fact that this solution does not involve LINQ or inception-style-loops

Comment: also `lists[i][c].ToString()` does not necessary need `ToString` conversion. In case if you have millions combinations (as I do) this might save some time

Answer (score 0):

This is permutation problem. You may take a look at this:

http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/09/16/permuterate

Comment: No, it's not permutations. It's combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem some time ago (generating combinations), I've used code from: http://www.merriampark.com/comb.htm . It's java, but I hadn't any problems to translate it into C#.

Answer (score 0):

Put A,B,C in matrix!
M=[A,B,C]

```
recursive_caller(d,params):
    if d == len(M):
        function(params)
        return

    for i in M[d]:
        params[d]=i
        recursive_caller(d+1,params)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that what you really *want*, is neither a permutation, nor a combination, per se. You want to look at the [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741364/efficient-cartesian-product-algorithm)) of several sets, the iteration over which may involve iterating through combinations of individual sets.

However, this is unlike a combination problem, because you are looking for the ways to choose 1 element from each set. The number of ways to do this is the size of the set. Combinations problems usually involve choose *k*-many things from a set of *n*-many things, where *k*=1 or *n* is trivial.

Several methods of producing iterators in C# have been discussed [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/574570-cross-product-arrays). (Including one by Jon Skeet).

If you are using .NET, you may also be interested in developed combinatorics modules, such as [KwCombinatorics](http://kwcombinatorics.codeplex.com/) at CodePlex.

**edit** Now, with LINQ to the rescue:

```
private void cartesian1()
{
    textAppend("Cartesian 1");
    var setA = new[] { "whole wheat", "white", "rye" };
    var setB = new[] { "cold cut", "veggie", "turkey", "roast beef" };
    var setC = new[] { "everything", "just mayo" };

    var query =
        from bread in setA
        from meat in setB
        from toppings in setC
        let sandwich = String.Format("{1} on {0} with {2}",
            bread, meat, toppings)
        select sandwich;

    foreach( string sandwich in query )
    {
        textAppend(sandwich);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of @Guffa's answer. I am by no means a creator of this code.

```
List<int> lists = new List<int> { 3, 2, 4 };

int[] cnt = new int[lists.Count];
int index;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", cnt));
    index = cnt.Length - 1;
    do
    {
        cnt[index] = (cnt[index] + 1) % lists[index];
    } while (cnt[index--] == 0 && index != -1);
} while (index != -1 || cnt[0] != 0);
```

Instead of using `List<List<int>>` - with possible values - use `List<int>` describing the amount of elements in collection. The output is the same an in original answer. The performance is better.