# Finding cartesian product in Java

Tags: java, math, set, cartesian-product

I want to find cartesian product of set of elements. Here's an example

example 1:

```
sets : (ab) (bc) (ca)
```

cartesian product is:

```
abc aba acc aca bbc bba bcc bca
```

example 2:

```
sets : (zyx) b c
```

cartesian product is:

```
zbc ybc xbc
```

So I am thinking of an algorithm to execute in Java which can find cartesian product of particular amount of groups defined at compile time at the start.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`Sets.cartesianProduct()`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#cartesianProduct(java.util.Set...)) method from [Google's Guava libraries](https://github.com/google/guava) to generate Cartesian products:

```java
com.google.common.collect.Sets.cartesianProduct(Set[] yourSets)
```

If only everything was that easy!

Answer (score 2):

Define your own Iterator/Iterable:

```
import java.util.*;

class CartesianIterator <T> implements Iterator <List <T>> {

    private final List <List <T>> lilio;    
    private int current = 0;
    private final long last;

    public CartesianIterator (final List <List <T>> llo) {
        lilio = llo;
        long product = 1L;
        for (List <T> lio: lilio)
            product *= lio.size ();
        last = product;
    } 

    public boolean hasNext () {
        return current != last;
    }

    public List <T> next () {
        ++current;
        return get (current - 1, lilio);
    }

    public void remove () {
        ++current;
    }

    private List<T> get (final int n, final List <List <T>> lili) {
        switch (lili.size ())
        {
            case 0: return new ArrayList <T> (); // no break past return;
            default: {
                List <T> inner = lili.get (0);
                List <T> lo = new ArrayList <T> ();
                lo.add (inner.get (n % inner.size ()));
                lo.addAll (get (n / inner.size (), lili.subList (1, lili.size ())));
                return lo;
            }
        }
    }
}

class CartesianIterable <T> implements Iterable <List <T>> {

    private List <List <T>> lilio;  

    public CartesianIterable (List <List <T>> llo) {
        lilio = llo;
    }

    public Iterator <List <T>> iterator () {
        return new CartesianIterator <T> (lilio);
    }
}
```

And test it with your Data:

```
class CartesianIteratorTest {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        List <Character> la = Arrays.asList (new Character [] {'a', 'b'});
        List <Character> lb = Arrays.asList (new Character [] {'b', 'c'});      
        List <Character> lc = Arrays.asList (new Character [] {'c', 'a'});
        List <List <Character>> llc = new ArrayList <List <Character>> ();
        llc.add (la);
        llc.add (lb);
        llc.add (lc);

        CartesianIterable <Character> ci = new CartesianIterable <Character> (llc);
        for (List<Character> lo: ci)
            show (lo);

        la = Arrays.asList (new Character [] {'x', 'y', 'z'});
        lb = Arrays.asList (new Character [] {'b'});    
        lc = Arrays.asList (new Character [] {'c'});
        llc = new ArrayList <List <Character>> ();
        llc.add (la);
        llc.add (lb);
        llc.add (lc);

        ci = new CartesianIterable <Character> (llc);
        for (List<Character> lo: ci)
            show (lo);    
    }

    public static void show (List <Character> lo) {
        System.out.print ("(");
        for (Object o: lo)
            System.out.print (o);
        System.out.println (")");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
(abc)
(bbc)
(acc)
(bcc)
(aba)
(bba)
(aca)
(bca)
(xbc)
(ybc)
(zbc)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note:* A `Set` is *a collection that contains no duplicate elements*. If you have duplicate elements in different sets, then each set from the Cartesian product will contain only one of them.

You can create a generic method to get a Cartesian product and specify the types of collections to store it. For example, a `Set` or a `List`.

#### Cartesian product using *map and reduce* approach

- The `map` method represents each element of a collection as a singleton collection and specifies the format of the result.
- The `reduce` method sums pairs of 2D collections into a single 2D collection.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVZNb9swDL33V3A5FHbgOmuOWZqtDQrssAJDcxx2UG2mUSpLhiS3y9b@9oySP9M4aQfMgJFQIh8p8pHymj2ys3X6sN3yLFfawpoW4sJyEQ8/neytLQuZWK5kvCjyXHDUPTrGamSZMz/JizvBE0gEMwZuGJfw5wToqdaNZZZ@HhVPIaPdYGE1l/c/fgLT9yaslN3zjRs7XSC9XmM2A4PWwIXfiNUyaDTrh5Td@uByEMHgahBGzcqVW5l3V@Zu5XIQhhTyYY9JTiK5TJi2aDiT37VKi8QGX5lZ0dZkIvEp8oER0A5OCdYCObkP6VJrtnGbu1gN2GgEqrB5YSNQOkVNWdvAI9ObRmOxMRazmLTinNxZIQOrSs@BP0DYie24souj1n4pYxgNh6XxEL7kTLMMEiUM2BUClxSWEwV6hoBadiTzykzOlfBmpuKRU3dyebyO5SvD6fUMvKLd5FgbocAMpa3Fw8a3PcYabaFlb6zVlq8emXrsumSQlzWrYbJCWJ4L7AEa9XB@eh3BLeAvizI1MG9s6HyzxuEeP3ZYXreg03T5jLownw9hu4J1O4solawweQC@7NTR5wstakOtiCCVBVkI0ViRcuBreHHhN@D5uaRCJYd1Wp3QEq7NtanGRBDudS5FJJU887BMpl7ALLeb/dR2nnjJBcUbkA6c@WPChyq201Mnxob/xiCEGXzs9akx12gcjZAlqy6nWJfWjDIChjpEoFVyj2vdiDKWd8I5fOAdA3Tqi3KE0mzCMK5cBFUhlTaxVW1VfR3C8DAsna3Em1a8mh2OoNeXMwv6PBCyKbKM1f2eM06EoT9cSmrpo@XSSIzGwCXoPHKq47BK1PnbmXKkVdkdl971O122TBHM3lCqvcl55XX8ttcd7zJh1F/0kmerGk4cI0RvvX0Q492il4FF5ZnGbwe0d7KWHZNJeax/AHkn345WR7gLzt8AbZX@I@sUTSr9xA3SgIByNjiP@yxT@loY7OTDxF69At@93EblbeT7nu5UoAG4UmlUTS3X90ulie0WUxrj7pb0ds1Eb0ZuddNXv9Dcqb7/3j2Z@4Zld6aUoPFa0YfTYOB7qCdbfcl1Ji4e99nTJuFlu/0L)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Set<String>> sets = List.of(
            Set.of("A", "B"), Set.of("B", "C"), Set.of("C", "A"));

    List<Set<String>> cpSet = cartesianProduct(HashSet::new, sets);
    List<List<String>> cpList = cartesianProduct(ArrayList::new, sets);

    // output, order may vary
    System.out.println(toString(cpSet));
    //ABC, AB, AC, AC, BC, BA, BC, BCA
    System.out.println(toString(cpList));
    //ABC, ABA, ACC, ACA, BBC, BBA, BCC, BCA
}
```

```java
/**
 * @param cols the input collection of collections
 * @param nCol the supplier of the output collection
 * @param <E>  the type of the element of the collection
 * @param <R>  the type of the return collections
 * @return List<R> the cartesian product of the multiple collections
 */
public static <E, R extends Collection<E>> List<R> cartesianProduct(
        Supplier<R> nCol, Collection<? extends Collection<E>> cols) {
    // check if the input parameters are not null
    if (nCol == null || cols == null) return null;
    return cols.stream()
        // non-null and non-empty collections
        .filter(col -> col != null && col.size() > 0)
        // represent each element of a collection as a singleton collection
        .map(col -> col.stream()
            .map(e -> Stream.of(e).collect(Collectors.toCollection(nCol)))
            // Stream<List<R>>
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        // summation of pairs of inner collections
        .reduce((col1, col2) -> col1.stream()
            // combinations of inner collections
            .flatMap(inner1 -> col2.stream()
                // concatenate into a single collection
                .map(inner2 -> Stream.of(inner1, inner2)
                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(nCol))))
            // list of combinations
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        // otherwise an empty list
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
}
```

```java
// supplementary method, returns a formatted string
static <E extends String> String toString(List<? extends Collection<E>> cols) {
    return cols.stream().map(col -> String.join("", col))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Cartesian product of an arbitrary number of sets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67174557/16497917)</sup>