# Implement Cartesian product of several collections by Java Stream

Tags: java, generics, collections, java-stream, cartesian-product

Right now I can only implement the Cartesian product of two collections, here is the code:

```
public static <T1, T2, R extends Collection<Pair<T1, T2>>>
R getCartesianProduct(
        Collection<T1> c1, Collection<T2> c2,
        Collector<Pair<T1, T2>, ?, R> collector) {
    return c1.stream()
            .flatMap(e1 -> c2.stream().map(e2 -> new Pair<>(e1, e2)))
            .collect(collector);
}
```

This code works fine in **IntelliJ**, but not in **Eclipse**. Both with compiler compliance level of 1.8:

```
The method collect(Collector<? super Object,A,R>)
in the type Stream<Object> is not applicable for
the arguments (Collector<Pair<T1,T2>,capture#5-of ?,R>)
```

Here is Pair.java:

```
public class Pair<T1, T2> implements Serializable {
    protected T1 first;
    protected T2 second;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1360822168806852921L;

    public Pair(T1 first, T2 second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public Pair(Pair<T1, T2> pair) {
        this(pair.getFirst(), pair.getSecond());
    }

    public T1 getFirst() {
        return this.first;
    }

    public T2 getSecond() {
        return this.second;
    }

    public void setFirst(T1 o) {
        this.first = o;
    }

    public void setSecond(T2 o) {
        this.second = o;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "(" + this.first + ", " + this.second + ")";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(!(o instanceof Pair))
            return false;
        Pair p = (Pair) o;
        if(!this.first.equals(p.first))
            return false;
        if(!this.second.equals(p.second))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 1;
        hash = hash * 31 + this.first.hashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + this.second.hashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

How to fix this error?

Is there an elegant way to implement the Cartesian product of several collections? Suppose we have class `tuple`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eclipse has problems with type inference.  If you add a type hint  `.<Pair<T1,T2>>flatMap`, it compiles fine.

If I may suggest a different approach, consider making your cartesianProduct not do the entire stream and collection but merely be a helper for `flatMap`:

```
static <T1, T2, R> Function<T1, Stream<R>> crossWith(
         Supplier<? extends Stream<T2>> otherSup, 
         BiFunction<? super T1, ? super T2, ? extends R> combiner
) {
    return t1 -> otherSup.get().map(t2 -> combiner.apply(t1, t2));
}
```

Now you only need to create a `Pair` if you want the result to contains `Pair`s  and you can do a higher-order cartesian product by applying `flatMap` several times:

```
List<String> letters = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

List<Pair<String, Integer>> board = letters.stream()
                .flatMap(crossWith(numbers::stream, Pair::new))
                .collect(toList());


List<String> ops = Arrays.asList("+", "-", "*", "/");

List<String> combinations = letters.stream()
                .flatMap(crossWith(ops::stream, String::concat))
                .flatMap(crossWith(letters::stream, String::concat))
                .collect(toList());   // triple cartesian product
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that generalizes to the case that the number of requisite flatMap-applications (i. e. the order of the product) is not known at compile time.

```
BinaryOperator<Function<String,Stream<String>>> kleisli = (f,g) -> s -> f.apply(s).flatMap(g);

List<String> cartesian(int n, Collection<String> coll) {
    return coll.stream()
           .flatMap( IntStream.range(1, n).boxed()
                     .map(_any -> crossWith(coll::stream, String::concat)) // create (n-1) appropriate crossWith instances
                     .reduce(s -> Stream.of(s), kleisli)                   // compose them sequentially
                    )                                                      // flatMap the stream with the entire function chain
           .collect(toList());
}
```

You'll find details of how this works at [my own blog](http://sebastian-millies.blogspot.de/2015/09/cartesian-products-with-kleisli.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Supplier` as a parameter for the `Collectors.toCollection` method. This simplifies the code and makes it more generic. The *Cartesian product* of different types and numbers of collections and their elements.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVVRb9owEH7vr7jxUBKWpiuPlLJ21aRN2rQJJu1h2oMJB5g6dmQ73djU387OTiAJQdBNWiQItr@77/zdZ7Nij@xiNXvYbHiaKW1hRRNxbrmIe9dnrbl5LhPLlYwneZYJjvoAxliNLHXhZ4lgxsAXNBZ@nwE9WT4VPAFjmaXXo@IzSBmXwcRqLhffvgPTCxOWYPdM0A7fS4sL1CNgcOMmYjUPriLoh9cN2P2SaZZYB5xWwG6vG0H3ZbcG/sCNHRaMI0gI6iYctnPXiaDzpkPYRmb3@TRdYWJHFJDRkIISpi0azuRnrWZ5YoN3zCxpaTCQ@CMCFsE0gmSf1n/VcrnxoWR3WrO1W2yl2@W7vASV2yy3ESg9Q01KruGR6XVV@9pYTGNCxRnt1goZ@Orrwh2CON4S81TwXfZ6RUgPbjOSOQV5rwTYJYIpnQBq7sdFTZAoIdB7ZS@QFowHculwzG3UxVYBZi9iOB6Bj7DrDLc0Gm2u5SGacsWBdrJCVui6jU5zYXkm8ADrpX/fOoNrNOYr05KMYoIOWX@JyQPOOuEBLw/HgD8typmB@13O4Wtq8rjd3Z38vgVbAZ2kUTM6jmMvWP1IUN99IcDnlfjcgFQWZC7EDkjrgW/TzY1fCLeiuUFlgXIyGIfgXWfKExx44kapJb1U8sLlACZnfoBpZtdtLWtPPOeCjqbLCRcjB4UXRVVwfu6GseG/MAhhBK8Ocmp07UBpAVmyBBSYugH1k9WIgRkaG2qYQKva9qhXlLJsW05QE73ZvbCorRCkXVgjGbpUk@L2o9sEw7ik36ZX2sRWVQS@O2F4JO2/JiDBTJ6mzGtCGmWMa@N@cCnJLUc7pZE8ioHThm5Z@u6Hz9Do6rRIzrgqnXLpy3pmOZWBBLMfSWUfclWaqH@atcEuE0ZnlD7EbNXOKsd8crDVvoh@s99FYVGxp/7pglo7q1QdDIpt/UWSZzrlRHd258hfyFWv/otDFd3E@gc3SPcI7F8hbV8q/VYY8uURHzqyeIE2CHd/X0@bzR8)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer> a = Set.of(1, 2);
    Set<Character> b = Set.of('*', '+');
    List<String> c = List.of("A", "B");

    Set<Set<Object>> cpSet = cartesianProduct(HashSet::new, a, b, c);
    List<List<Object>> cpList = cartesianProduct(ArrayList::new, a, b, c);

    // output, order may vary
    System.out.println(cpSet);
    System.out.println(cpList);
}
```

```java
/**
 * @param nCol the supplier of the output collection
 * @param cols the input array of collections
 * @param <R>  the type of the return collection
 * @return the cartesian product of the multiple collections
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <R extends Collection<?>> R cartesianProduct(
        Supplier nCol, Collection<?>... cols) {
    // check if supplier is not null
    if (nCol == null) return null;
    return (R) Arrays.stream(cols)
        // non-null and non-empty collections
        .filter(col -> col != null && col.size() > 0)
        // represent each element of a collection as a singleton collection
        .map(col -> (Collection<Collection<?>>) col.stream()
            .map(e -> Stream.of(e).collect(Collectors.toCollection(nCol)))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(nCol)))
        // summation of pairs of inner collections
        .reduce((col1, col2) -> (Collection<Collection<?>>) col1.stream()
            // combinations of inner collections
            .flatMap(inner1 -> col2.stream()
                // concatenate into a single collection
                .map(inner2 -> Stream.of(inner1, inner2)
                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(nCol))))
            // collection of combinations
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(nCol)))
        // otherwise an empty collection
        .orElse((Collection<Collection<?>>) nCol.get());
}
```

Output (order may vary):

```
[[1,A,*],[1,B,*],[1,A,+],[A,2,*],[1,B,+],[2,B,*],[A,2,+],[2,B,+]]
[[2,+,A],[2,+,B],[2,*,A],[2,*,B],[1,+,A],[1,+,B],[1,*,A],[1,*,B]]
```

---

<sup>See also the less generic version: [Finding cartesian product in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68476861/16497917)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *more generic* solution that accepts any type of [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) and allows you to choose the types of *inner* and *outer* return collections.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVVLT9tAEL7zK6YXZCPjlLRwCJC2QkWtlFYVgVPVw8aZJAvrXWt3DU0Lvz2dXT9iJw5w6Ep5zPqb@ebtW3bPDm@nd6sVTzOlLdzSRZxbLuKD072tu1kuE8uVjMd5lgmOugNjrEaWOvW9RDBj4IJpi4Yz@UOraZ5Y@LsHdLJ8IngCxjJLP/eKTyFlXAZjq7mc//wFTM9NWILdGXFjz75Ki3PUQ2Bw7m9iNQuOIuiHp23gSMn5ECYN1LtRBO9HDdwY7dmlUMwOISEciQ52HB9fRnASn1wStIX1dr/n6YT4SSVzMt2TarIRYlDrVecLMwvCDgYSHyL4pDVbOvVSLqlZBJMIkrBJ7Ekde4OYRHf9KuJNqrYjVW66mHs9ULnNchuB0lPUVJ4l3DO9XCdlaSymMaHijIpmhQzqrDTz3AUrYyhhTwVt7@Cg0DqAjxnTLAV1oUTE6cv5grrHpSRPNNpcS0iUEOgbEkzZkBvqhDCFE1xSJE0NNWtIZkPv7HpYOk@GUdtlhk7BLhBQYIrSmhcM3FQGmro7vN/UverS9fE/o1s@Yet5g6wcOLLAIM2F5ZnADqd7HQN5dh3BDeBvi3JKM1zrUGYiuOp6cEO9eeUtbXVltS5cZL6iUN9Qnlx5o63G9adhvvH3Q01/7eaBatzcE9S3yQKTO@Czui0MbRMEqSzIXIgaSojA@QPn5/4BPD56byo5rPLthHVDr4tgynUXhC3/yQWp5KE3yeTUC5hmdrmd/PLEMy6ovgE9h0MfE7wpfdrfd2Js@B8MQhjC2y0ujZlGQ00JyJJF1aFF2RsdzygLYGi5CrRqu4cqT1KWNdzoDrAGooONi5VPewTDuDQblPVS2sRWrYsXuPyGYYe5lxRVhyIFb/I0ZdVEZ4xrP5nFpO3MtkbqSwxcnPTyoO9@WMZ7tDtg11gqnXDp6V5BUxRWMPuNMuWhRyVLfzdLzSQTRk1OH2Kxqi7drrq1yuLJ@u3aFA5Ehc/9buKWx@vcDwaFu88ovbLsO7La3srrHP@3LlG0QvUDNxjRQMLmLLabQ@nPwqC3FM/RBmH9knparf4B)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> a = List.of(1, 2);
    List<Long> b = List.of(3L, 4L);
    Set<Float> c = Set.of(5.5F, 6.6F);

    Set<List<Number>> cpListSet = cartesianProduct(
            HashSet::new, ArrayList::new, Set.of(a, b, c));

    List<Set<Number>> cpSetList = cartesianProduct(
            ArrayList::new, HashSet::new, List.of(a, b, c));

    // output, order may vary
    System.out.println(cpListSet);
    System.out.println(cpSetList);
}
```

```java
/**
 * @param oCol,iCol outer/inner return collection supplier
 * @param cols      input collection of collections
 * @param <T>       supertype of the elements of collections
 * @param <U>       type of the inner return collection
 * @param <R>       type of the outer return collection
 * @return a Cartesian product of a multiple collections
 */
public static <T, U extends Collection<T>, R extends Collection<U>> R
cartesianProduct(Supplier<R> oCol, Supplier<U> iCol,
                 Collection<Collection<? extends T>> cols) {
    // check if suppliers are not null
    if (oCol == null || iCol == null) return null;
    return cols.stream()
        // non-null and non-empty collections
        .filter(col -> col != null && col.size() > 0)
        // represent each element of a collection as a singleton collection
        .map(col -> col.stream()
            .map(e -> Stream.of(e).collect(Collectors.toCollection(iCol)))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(oCol)))
        // summation of pairs of inner collections
        .reduce((col1, col2) -> col1.stream()
            // combinations of inner collections
            .flatMap(inner1 -> col2.stream()
                // concatenate into a single collection
                .map(inner2 -> Stream.of(inner1, inner2)
                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(iCol))))
            // collection of combinations
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(oCol)))
        // otherwise, an empty collection
        .orElse(oCol.get());
}
```

Output, order may vary:

```
[[2,3,6.6],[1,3,6.6],[2,4,6.6],[1,4,6.6],[1,4,5.5],[1,3,5.5],[2,4,5.5],[2,3,5.5]]
[[5.5,1,3],[6.6,1,3],[5.5,1,4],[6.6,1,4],[5.5,2,3],[6.6,2,3],[5.5,2,4],[6.6,2,4]]
```

---

<sup>See also the less generic version: [Cartesian product of multiple lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68692855/16596785)</sup>