# How do I generate a Cartesian product in Java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, cartesian-product

I have a number of `ArrayList` with each `ArrayList` having objects and each one can have different length.  I need to generate permutation like in the below example:

Suppose I have 2 `ArrayList`:

> ArrayList `A`  has object `a`, object `b` and object `c`
> ArrayList `B`  has object `d`, object `e`

Then the output should be 6 new `ArrayList` with these combinations:

> Combination `1` object `a` and object `d`,
> Combination `2` object `a` and object `e`,
> Combination `3` object `b` and object `d`,
> Combination `4` object `b` and object `e`,
> Combination `5` object `c` and object `d`,
> Combination `6` object `c` and object `e`,

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5):

With `Java8` streams

```java
List<String> a = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
List<String> b = Arrays.asList("d", "e");
String[][] AB = a.stream()
        .flatMap(ai -> b.stream()
                .map(bi -> new String[]{ai, bi}))
        .toArray(String[][]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(AB));
```

output

```
[[a, d], [a, e], [b, d], [b, e], [c, d], [c, e]]
```

To get as `List`

```java
List<List<String>> ll = a.stream()
        .flatMap(ai -> b.stream()
                .map(bi -> new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(ai, bi))))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Guava 19+

```
Lists.cartesianProduct(List...)
```

**E.g.**:

```
List<Object> list1 = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
List<Object> list2 = Arrays.asList("d", "e");
System.out.println(Lists.cartesianProduct(list1, list2));
```

**Output**:

```
[[a, d], [a, e], [b, d], [b, e], [c, d], [c, e]]
```

Answer (score 4):

With an Iterable+Iterator:

```
import java.util.*;

class CartesianIterator <T> implements Iterator <List <T>> {

    private final List <List <T>> lilio;    
    private int current = 0;
    private final long last;

    public CartesianIterator (final List <List <T>> llo) {
        lilio = llo;
        long product = 1L;
        for (List <T> lio: lilio)
            product *= lio.size ();
        last = product;
    } 

    public boolean hasNext () {
        return current != last;
    }

    public List <T> next () {
        ++current;
        return get (current - 1, lilio);
    }

    public void remove () {
        ++current;
    }

    private List<T> get (final int n, final List <List <T>> lili) {
        switch (lili.size ())
        {
            case 0: return new ArrayList <T> (); // no break past return;
            default: {
                List <T> inner = lili.get (0);
                List <T> lo = new ArrayList <T> ();
                lo.add (inner.get (n % inner.size ()));
                lo.addAll (get (n / inner.size (), lili.subList (1, lili.size ())));
                return lo;
            }
        }
    }
}

class CartesianIterable <T> implements Iterable <List <T>> {

    private List <List <T>> lilio;  

    public CartesianIterable (List <List <T>> llo) {
        lilio = llo;
    }

    public Iterator <List <T>> iterator () {
        return new CartesianIterator <T> (lilio);
    }
}
```

You can use them in a simplified for-loop:

```
class CartesianIteratorTest {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        List <Character> la = Arrays.asList (new Character [] {'a', 'b', 'c'});
        List <Character> lb = Arrays.asList (new Character [] {'d', 'e'});      
        List <List <Character>> llc = new ArrayList <List <Character>> ();
        llc.add (la);
        llc.add (lb);

        CartesianIterable <Character> ci = new CartesianIterable <Character> (llc);
        for (List<Character> lo: ci)
            show (lo);
    }

    public static void show (List <Character> lo) {
        System.out.print ("(");
        for (Object o: lo)
            System.out.print (o);
        System.out.println (")");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Cartesian product of multiple lists using the *map and reduce* approach

- The [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method represents each element of the list as a singleton list and specifies the format of the result.

  Intermediate output:

  ```
  [[a], [b], [c]]
  [[d], [e]]
  [[f]]
  ```
- The [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) method sums pairs of 2D lists into a single 2D list.

  Final output:

  ```
  [[a, d, f], [a, e, f], [b, d, f], [b, e, f], [c, d, f], [c, e, f]]
  ```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVTBbtswDL3nK7gcCntI3TXHNAkwFLttwID0NuygKEyjVpYEie6QDf32jJJdz46TdgPmg2ORfOQj@aIH8SQurUPzsHk8HFTprCd4YGNRkdLF@5vRwBbIoyijayS1CAFuhScMSpiv3m4qSfBrBPy4aq2VhECC@OfJqg2UQplsRV6Z@2/fQfj7kDfB8fmsAs1r7xIELOCj92IfChGiJxuL8QTG6/iS4/zmNGw9hG0iAs8i5BCxjcH96C6EMY5B8qjtrJ9FTGA9AZl36l5dga3IVdRaVvtAWBZsLRznJm0y6RrE8@jEGOd3yw6hu8jlmEbfrfmjN2UmIXcoH0FtwVgCU2ndOtmWJQQsFsmTg0eqvEmHXidtXXDN2u0WykqTchrrsm14kyMZG/1keevtjsfoPdDOhiYDfwtioWBLFYTZpAOWjvaDHMVWaUKfmoDLun14V/cCFxfpXAT1E7MclvDhJAmPzmNAwzWE3NUpUGMZLSKwMgOrQCPZuqMhh1K4HoG25eS5tVqjJGVNmM3aVHFhQzYdVquUY97b7vIsoJB1lZdq1oeCbBJmnp/smtWHvsSNEoTHMm2zOsTH7I9oZ7NGtScz1l1HWdS75EjbTu/M6DyylDDLdKDrCfB7mqcp8vG8cLqqtOVaGZGmGysrY9AfqXGoGS3oC28mBV839aZv1@vVNZIHZ@Lw/qLPk5JJ5aexfL3rwm4bSpO6j@nbVAY9xZWzzFLCf4C/Kp9XN5CEz5PvbuI/ytTSDv0PxRcE3zzpDjijJOs/6YDdf1uRwpvkL3fs8@HwGw)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> a = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    List<String> b = Arrays.asList("d", "e");
    List<String> c = Arrays.asList("f");

    List<List<String>> cp = cartesianProduct(Arrays.asList(a, b, c));
    // output
    System.out.println(cp);
}
```

```java
public static <T> List<List<T>> cartesianProduct(List<List<T>> lists) {
    // check if not null
    if (lists == null) return null;
    // cartesian product of multiple lists
    return lists.stream()
            // only those lists that are not null and not empty
            .filter(list -> list != null && list.size() > 0)
            // represent each list element as a singleton list
            .map(list -> list.stream().map(Collections::singletonList)
                    // Stream<List<List<T>>>
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            // intermediate output
            .peek(System.out::println)
            // stream of lists into a single list
            .reduce((lst1, lst2) -> lst1.stream()
                    // combinations of inner lists
                    .flatMap(inner1 -> lst2.stream()
                            // concatenate into a single list
                            .map(inner2 -> Stream.of(inner1, inner2)
                                    .flatMap(List::stream)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList())))
                    // list of combinations
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            // otherwise an empty list
            .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Cartesian product of an arbitrary number of sets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67174557/16436544)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Use nested *for* loops that would have a loop for every ArrayList as below. I am assuming I have two ArrayLists - intList and stringList. I can have two nested *for* loops (one for each list) to generate the permutation.

```java
for (Integer i : intList) {
    for (String s : stringList) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Guava... Here is an example of a Cartesian product of a list with itself:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  //How to do a cartesian product of a List of items
  List<Integer> listToSelfMultiply = Arrays.asList(
      new Integer(1), new Integer(2), new Integer(3), new Integer(4));
  LinkedList<Integer> linkedListCopy = Lists.newLinkedList(listToSelfMultiply);
  for (Integer i : listToSelfMultiply) {
    if (linkedListCopy.size() == 1) {
      break;
    }
    linkedListCopy.remove();
    System.out.println("" + Arrays.deepToString(
        Lists.cartesianProduct(Arrays.asList(i), linkedListCopy).toArray()) + "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Cartesian product of multiple lists

You can use the [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) method with *three* parameters:

- *`identity`* - specify the result stub.

  ```
  List<List<T>>
  ```
- *`accumulator`* - append elements of lists to the result.

  ```
  List<List<T>> result, List<T> list
  ```
- *`combiner`* - is used in parallel mode, combines the results.

  ```
  List<List<T>> result1, List<List<T>> result2
  ```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVXRbtowFH3nK@54qBIE6do@tkVj3fa0SZPat2kPrmNaU8e2bKcTq/h2dn2dpKEpgkWCkPie4@N7js2KPbOZsUKvyqftVlbWuAArfFnUQapicjkavPPBCVbFoRFXzHu4YS4IL5n@6UxZ8wAvI8DrdDKhO0zgk2WOVaCkDx7Co2h@LY2DqlZBWiU5C9LoN4Cruzk@RkBYWwFmSUAQSlRCh67YiVA7TXWdFrBJTFN0Sndb3@NM4ANOxon9O/Jd0dfdfA78zUqy3WFSnTfLoyWeAn8U/AnkEqTmppL6AUoWGEgP2gTQtVJdNRZlaeHX1zSSQ6P8xigleGyAL0RlwzpOmeWXHbSpI3RjQJZ3oz052uhZpAamS3ogugQc1BdLqYJwJApmaX3wIWmDkxN6Lrz8K7Ic5vDx3QmTmNYaj20IBhh47IRKPg@ndQKbKzJEyxJ9lChwBt4KLpdrctEJj7FA7vp@gG6vfs/SbMFo6tuebubTvVyohHFeYxZZwEzOgFncEmUbNP@6PFzcq8C9fFkanxIoj61NL/ZbN7QGpfxgNpNaC9eaczy@46mQQ6hI8HI0KF5N6IFaCpgJ8QcWzjFq5tU86eol9JiLuApWlqjoP6HNBiCG45Gb/HCn0HvKPVqMG/heajqI/GGHeIpZGzfjfBHMMVFL00RX4zFRe1HiroF44iGRgsqUYtoW@V7c/KG8nU2byvP8sOENJNqxUCprgZejI2xosPtrNw3PZvTOuftsZAkVkzq7DQ537q/fwNzDzsFKIUujmPwzzB9lzxfMU4fHi/EUxp/HPbm7kPMh5CZCvuyHXAwhXyPkW4TsYvpA/NewiBz8dexSKfRGnePnIu8JwDCYOtj69SS5XfsgqgLfFhbpg9IZt10zN9vtPw)

```java
/**
 * @param lists the lists for multiplication
 * @param <T>   the type of list element
 * @return the Cartesian product
 */
public static <T> List<List<T>> cartesianProduct(List<List<T>> lists) {
    // check if incoming data is not null
    if (lists == null) return Collections.emptyList();
    return lists.stream()
        // non-null and non-empty lists
        .filter(list -> list != null && list.size() > 0)
        // stream of lists into a single list
        .reduce(// identity - specify the result stub
                Collections.singletonList(Collections.emptyList()),
                // accumulator - append elements of lists to the result
                (result, list) -> result.stream()
                        .flatMap(inner -> list.stream()
                                .map(el -> {
                                    List<T> nList = new ArrayList<>(inner);
                                    nList.add(el);
                                    return nList;
                                }))
                        // list of combinations
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()),
                // combiner - is used in parallel mode, combines the results
                (result1, result2) -> {
                    result1.addAll(result2);
                    return result1;
                });
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList("A", "B");
    List<String> l2 = Arrays.asList("C", "D");
    List<String> l3 = Arrays.asList("E", "F");

    List<List<String>> cp = cartesianProduct(Arrays.asList(l1, l2, l3));
    // output
    System.out.println(cp);
}
```

Output:

```
[[A,C,E],[A,C,F],[A,D,E],[A,D,F],[B,C,E],[B,C,F],[B,D,E],[B,D,F]]
```

---

<sup>See also: [Cartesian product of 3 collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68694089/16596785)</sup>