# Joining two lists in java

Tags: list, join, java

I have lists of different classes, say A and B respectively. Definition of these classes is as follows-

```
class A {
 int field1;
 int field2;
}

class B {
 int field1;
 int field3;
}

class C {
 int field1;
 int field2;
 int field3;
}
```

I want to perform a join operation (similar to database join) on A and B, over field1 and populate the result in C.

I can iterate over the lists and do it. But, just wanted to check whether there are any library methods which does similar sort of thing.

Comment: I have never used it myself so I am not sure enough to post that as an answer. I have heard that LINQ provides an API to query collections the same way you'd query a relational database. I know there are LINQ implementations (or LINQ-like libraries) for Java, maybe you should look at those.

Answer (score 0):

If these are the only fields you're using, just iterate manually.

For larger data sets, group your data into Collections and [apply a Cartesian Product algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714108/cartesian-product-of-arbitrary-sets-in-java).

Comment: Actually, there are many fields in each class. Just to make it simple, I gave this example.

Comment: So A and B should probably contain a method that returns the value of the fields as a Collection. C should have a method that gets two collections as an argument, computes their Cartesian Product, and populates its own fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can add objects of any class to the list(if your list is not generic-specified). But when you get each object back from the list, you will not know the object is of which type.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe by using a method in library in apache collections:

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.ListUtils;    

List<?> newListC = ListUtils.intersection(list1, list2);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Author asked to group by fields, not to find intersection of lists by their elements.