# Get all combinations of Strings

Tags: java, algorithm

I have requirement that need to get all combinations of given Strings.
For example 
I have a String of digits and some special charcters

```
String chars="0123456789@#$%&";
String guessedPw="authentic";
```

So I want to get combinations like this

1. $authentic%4
2. authentic#@
3. 5&authentic
4. authentic8

How should I improve my method to get all combinations?

This is the code that I have written.

but it doesn't give me all combinations.

```
private static String combination(String prefix, String s, String pw, String md5Pw) {
    String pwFound = "";
    if (s.length() > 0) {
        // System.out.println(prefix + s.charAt(0) + pw);

        String tempPw1 = prefix + s.charAt(0) + pw;
        System.out.println("pw1 : " + tempPw1);
        if (md5(tempPw1).equals(md5Pw)) {
            // String tempPw1;
            pwFound = tempPw1;

            return pwFound;

        }

        String tempPw2 = pw + prefix + s.charAt(0);


        if (md5(tempPw2).equals(md5Pw)) {
            // String tempPw1;
            pwFound = tempPw2;
            return pwFound;

        }

        pwFound = combination(prefix + s.charAt(0), s.substring(1), pw, md5Pw);
        pwFound = combination(prefix, s.substring(1), pw, md5Pw);
    }
    return pwFound;
}
```

Comment: *Is this possible to achieve using java?*  **Yes**  Can we close the question now?

Comment: Show some code Dilshan.

Comment: I have updated the question with what i have done so far.

Comment: _"get combinations like this"_ -- you have not specified the rules for generating combinations, so _"doesn't give me all combinations"_ is meaningless and we really cannot help you.

Comment: That's why I want to know how to improve this code to get all combinations

Comment: Bettr use regex. and also remove that word **using Java** from your question. Obvi that is possible.

Comment: I have updated.
Can you please show me example or something using regx.

Comment: I think you're looking for permutations, not combinations. You should search for how to create all n-letter permutations of a string. And be prepared to wait a very long time. The number of permutations is going to be huge.

Comment: Thanks @JimMischel for show me the way.

Comment: Do you limit password length? Do you realize number of such strings?

Comment: length is not a problem.
I just want to get match like that.

Answer (score 0):

Just if you don't want write own algo, you can use google.

Try to search for: "Generate Permutations".

For example, on this link: [Generate all combinations from multiple lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192796/generate-all-combinations-from-multiple-lists) there is a algo which you can use it (but with list).

```
void GeneratePermutations(List<List<Character>> Lists, List<String> result, int depth, String current)
{
    if(depth == Lists.size())
    {
       result.add(current);
       return;
     }

    for(int i = 0; i < Lists.get(depth).size(); ++i)
    {
        GeneratePermutations(Lists, result, depth + 1, current + Lists.get(depth).get(i));
    }
}
```

But sure, there are a lot of other ways.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code everything by your own then this is how you should approach your problem => 
Have a special character say ~ to denote guessedPw, and create another string say str = chars + "~". 
Now first you need to look for all possible combinations of str, finding which will take exponential time , and then for each found combination, you should generate all it's permutation , which is again factorial time complex.
 And then in the final string , you should replace all the occurrence of '~' with guessedPw, and get the answer string.
Here you go for the link for generating permutations and combinations : 
Link : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/

To find out combinations , you can use bit-masking if you have at max. 64 characters in the string , combinations from which you want to extract.

Comment: Link for Combinations : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/

Answer (score 0):

To make new combination, you can add one char as prefix or add one char as suffix. To avoid repeats, stop adding prefix when suffix exists

Pseudocode:

```
GenPass(CurrentString, boolAllowPrefix)

    check CurrentString, return it if good result

    check length limit, exit if too long

    for c in Chars 
        if (boolAllowPrefix)
             GenPass(Chars[i] + CurrentString, True)
        GenPass(s + Chars[i], False)
```

Delphi implementation to check

```
procedure GenPass(s: string; bPrefix: Boolean);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  List.Add(s);
  if Length(s) = MaxLen then
    Exit;
  if bPrefix then
     for i := 1 to Length(Chars) do
        GenPass(Chars[i] + s, True);
   for i := 1 to Length(Chars) do
       GenPass(s + Chars[i], False);
```

end;