# Combinations from n arrays picking one element from each array using Java

Tags: java, arrays, cartesian-product

I'm working on this algorithm exercice from GeeksForGeeks:

> Given a list of arrays (of any size, not limited to two arrays), find all combinations where each combination contains one element from each given array.
>
> **Examples:**
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 1 3
> 1 4
> 2 3
> 2 4
> ```

I tried to resolve it myself using this approach:

```
Initialize "result" list of arraylist.
For each element of the first array in the input list:
   depth = 1
   while(depth < list.size())
    arrayToCombineWithItsElmt = list.get(depth)
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayToCombineWithItsElmt.size(); i++)
      GenerateCombinations(result, arrayToCombineWithItsElmt(i))
    depth++
return result
```

> `generateCombinations(List<ArrayList> result, int element)` method should:
>
> 1. copy result list (which contains previous combinations)
> 2. remove all elements of result list
> 3. iterate over the copied list and for each Array add the element
> 4. Add the array to result list.

I didn't code (**using Java**) it as I felt that it's not correct (very complex way to solve).
From this brute force algorithm that I got after trying to resolve an example manually, how to optimize?

Comment: Isn't it just using two nested loops?

Comment: @AKSW: Only if it is allways two arrays. If the number of arrays is random you would need another solution like a recursive function.

Comment: I know that it's only for two arrays, I just saw the example

Comment: You can use recursion or an iterator based approach to solve it.

Comment: But this question has already been answered here, thus, it's a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192796/generate-all-combinations-from-multiple-lists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate all combinations from multiple lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192796/generate-all-combinations-from-multiple-lists)

Comment: @AKSW no it's not a duplicate, that one is using Strings and I checked answers and couldn't figure out exactly.. that helped me go with the approach I proposed here and I'm looking for a solution with consideration of my approach.

Comment: It doesn't matter of which type the elements are ... and the solution with the iterators works on generic types, thus, also works for numbers ...

Comment: Ok. If someone didn't understand the solutions, what should him do? thank you.

Comment: I edited the question @AKSW. I'm not looking for codes like mentioned as duplicate. I want to achieve requested output starting from the approach I've taken.