# Pair creation for Vectors and Hashsets

Tags: java, vector, logic, artificial-intelligence, hashset

I have k number of Vectors, each containing n number of elements.

I need to implement an algorithm that creates new Vectors in this manner:

e.g.: Given

```
V1: (e1, e2)
V2: (e3)
V3: (e4, e5, e6)
```

the desired output would be

```
newV1: (e1, e3, e4)
newV2: (e1, e3, e5)
newV3: (e1, e3, e6)
newV4: (e2, e3, e4)
```

and so on until it produces all the possible combinations in this way.

What I have done so far would potentially only work to produce just the first combination for each element of the first Vector (it would only produce `newV1`, `newV4`, etc):

```
//compute new subclauses
CNFClause expressionNegatedFinal = new CNFClause();
boolean visited = false;

expressionNegated.getSubclauses().get(0).print();
for (Literal l: expressionNegated.getSubclauses().get(0).getLiterals()) {

    CNFSubClause scNF = new CNFSubClause();
    scNF.getLiterals().add(l);
    for (int j=1; j<expressionNegated.getSubclauses().size(); j++) {

        for(Literal li: expressionNegated.getSubclauses().get(j).getLiterals()) {
             li.setVisited(true);
             scNF.getLiterals().add(li);
             break;
        }

    }  
    expressionNegatedFinal.getSubclauses().add(scNF);
}
```

How can I implement this?

Edit1: I need this to work for any k number of vectors greater or equal to 2 and with any n number of elements greater or equal to 1 inside each vector

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192796/generate-all-combinations-from-multiple-lists

Comment: Please explain how it's different. It sounds like you just want all permutations of N number of provided Vectors.