# Permute lists of lists

Tags: java, permutation

Given n arrays of random sizes, I need to permute them like this:

```
[a1, a2, a3]
[b1, b2]
[c1, c2]

[a1, b1, c1]
[a1, b1, c2]
[a1, b2, c1]
[a1, b2, c2]
[a2, b1, c1]
[a2, b1, c2]
[a2, b2, c1]
[a2, b2, c2]
[a3, b1, c1]
[a3, b1, c2]
[a3, b2, c1]
[a3, b2, c2]
```

**The columns order matters, lines dont.**

What is good way to achieve this. If possible, using this method contract:

```java
<T> List<List<T>> permute(List<T>... lists)
```

Comment: It looks like you need all combinations from n lists, but with a **fixed** length of 3. It's an important piece of information and you should include it in your question

Comment: There is no restriction about sizes

Answer (score 0):

What you're searching for is a combination, not a permutation.
May have a look at this:
[Generate all combinations from multiple lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192796/generate-all-combinations-from-multiple-lists)