# For loops without knowing needed quantity

Tags: java, list, for-loop, arraylist

I want to cycle through/access all possible combinations of the elements in a series of Lists in a clock-like fashion, but I will not know how many Lists there will be until runtime (i.e. I can't hardcode it). Normally, if I did know how many Lists there would be, I would use nested For loops in something like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < total1; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < total2; y++){
        for(int z = 0; z < total3; z++){
            //Handling code
        }
    }
}
```

Where the outermost loop represents the last List, and the innermost represents the first. However, because I do not know how many Lists there will be, I can't use this method, because I wouldn't know how many loops to use. Some things on the Internet said to use a recursive program that would repeatedly run for-loops, but I don't understand how this could reach the same result as the above method.

Is there a way to accomplish the same ends as the For-loops (accessing every combination of elements from the Lists, taking one element from each List) without knowing how many Lists/Loops are needed?

Edit:
As an example, if I have 3 Lists, each with 4 elements:

```
[1,3,6,5], [0,5,8,2], [9,7,1,6]
```

Then my output should be, essentially, 64 Lists containing all possible examples, e.g.:

```
[1,0,9], [3,0,9], [6,0,9], [5,0,9],
[1,5,9], [3,5,9], [6,5,9], [5,5,9],
[1,8,9], [3,8,9], [6,8,9], [5,8,9],
[1,2,9], [3,2,9], [6,2,9], [5,2,9],
[1,0,7], [3,0,7], [6,0,7], [5,0,7] //...etc
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's typically when a while loop would be used, no?

Comment: You should put this in context. It's hard to tell as it is currently written.

Comment: Depending on size of items in array and the necessity for optimal performance, recursion could be a consideration here.

Comment: To get this straight: You want to build the cartesian product of n lists where n is unknown at compile time?

Comment: If it's acceptable to use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) in your app, [`Lists.cartesianProduct`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#cartesianProduct-java.util.List-) does exactly what you seem to be trying to achieve.

Comment: I believe this a task is where recursion is afoot.

Comment: You need a stack to accomplish what you need and a backtracking algorithm.

Comment: @BjörnZurmaar Yes exactly, but I was unfamiliar with the term "cartesian product" until I searched for it just now

Comment: @sumitsu I'm fairly inexperienced with Guava but the code you linked in your comment looks perfect, I'll try it now and update if it works!

Comment: You might find [Cartesian product of arbitrary sets in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714108/cartesian-product-of-arbitrary-sets-in-java) helpful.