# find all vertical traversals of a multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, graph-algorithm, traversal

If I have the following multidimensional array (of an arbitrary size):

```
a,b,c

d,e,f

g,h,i
```

And I'd like to find all possible **vertical traversals** (adg, adh, aeh, aeg, aei, bdg, etc), how would I go about doing that in Java?

What's making this difficult for me is the fact that the array is of an arbitrary square size (you don't know if its a `2x2` or a `3x3` or `4x4`), so you can't just make `N` nested for `loops`, where `N = length of multidimensional array`. Any help would be great!

Edit: I am defining **vertical traversals** as either moving down and to the left, directly down, and down and to the right

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714108/cartesian-product-of-arbitrary-sets-in-java) to get your thinking started.  If you phrase your problem as just taking the cartesian cross product between sets, where each set is a row from the 2D array, then the problem becomes tractable.

Comment: If you would provide the **input format**, I'd say that's helpful to help you out. What do you mean by **arbitrary size**? input **N** then the matrix?

Comment: It seems like this problem is about two-dimensional arrays, not multi-dimensional arrays in general.

Comment: How is vertical traversal defined? Why is "afi" not part of the sample list?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to solve this problem but maybe you can go for a recursive [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 3;

    String arr[][] = {
            {"a", "b", "c"},
            {"d", "e", "f"},
            {"g", "h", "i"}
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        dfs(arr, 0, i, size, arr[0][i]);
    }
}

static void dfs(String[][] arr, int y, int x, int size, String curr) {
    if (y == size - 1) {
        System.out.println(curr);
    } else {
        if (x > 0) {
            dfs(arr, y + 1, x - 1, size, curr + arr[y + 1][x - 1]);
        }
        dfs(arr, y + 1 , x, size, curr + arr[y + 1][x]);
        if (x < size - 1) {
            dfs(arr, y + 1, x + 1, size, curr + arr[y + 1][x + 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

`dfs` will move `y` and `x` to adjacent cells that is strictly below current cell, and save its contents to `curr`. If `dfs` traversed to bottom, it will print `curr`.

---

Output:

```
adg
adh
aeg
aeh
aei
bdg
bdh
beg
beh
bei
bfh
bfi
ceg
ceh
cei
cfh
cfi
```

Comment: Does depth-first search dictate skipping 'adi' in this problem?

Comment: @JohnMcClane is 'adi' a vertical traversal?

Comment: I think yes, like 'adg'.

Comment: I noticed that 'adi', 'afi', 'afg' etc were not in the examples so I assumed that the 'traversal' is only from and to adjacent cells.

Comment: I so, then your solution is right. Why 'aeg' is skipped in the question then?

Comment: Didn't notice that - I think I may need more clear definition of 'traversal'.

Comment: Sorry for the late response guys. I am defining "traversal" as only from and to adjacent cells (down and to the left, directly down, and down and to the right)