# Missing the groovy combinations in Java 11

Tags: java

Groovy can make a complete combination from a n of n elements. A example of this would be:

```
[[1,2,3], [true,false], [A,B,C]].combinations()
```

result in:

```
[[1,true,A],[2,true,A],[3,true,A], [1,false,A],[2, false,A],[3, false,A], [1,false,B],[2, false,B],[3, false,B], [1,true,B],[2, true,B],[3, true,B] etc....
```

I am looking for something similar in java 11 like:
combinations({1,2,3}, {true, false}, {A,B,C})

I haven't had any luck. I prefer to use a library.

Comment: Looks like you want a cartesian product. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714108/cartesian-product-of-arbitrary-sets-in-java

Comment: If you're fine with using a library, you can also add the Groovy collections library to your Java project, perhaps